# Difference between helm repo add vs helm install

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have delved into the documentations of helm and still it is unclear what is the difference between the two. Here's what I understand so far

```
helm install -> install a helm chart 
helm repo add -> add a repo from the internet
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see Helm as a templating tool, which reads files from the `templates` directory, fills them with values from `values.yaml`, and deploys them into the Kubernetes cluster. These is all done by the `helm install` command. So, Helm install takes your chart and deploys it into the Kubernetes cluster.

One of the feature of Helm is `helm package`, which packages your chart into a single `*.tgz` file and then you can store it in the [Helm registry](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/registries/). A lot of Helm charts are stored that way, you can look, e.g., into [Artifact Hub](https://artifacthub.io/). If you find a chart you'd like to install from the Helm registry, you can add that remote repo into your local Helm registry using `helm repo add`. Then, `helm repo update` downloads a Helm chart to your local registry. Downloading a repo just downloads the Helm chart into your local registry, but it does not deploy anything into the Kubernetes cluster. To do that, you need to use `helm install`.